# docusign transform pdf field with text tab as required

Tags: docusignapi

i am integrating Docusign application in for my company, the requirment is that our customers create a template in our application. This template is a html page which we convert into pdf and send this pdf as a document to Docusign for signing. i have set transformPdfFields to true and the fields are transforming. I want the text field in pdf to be set as mandatory.
 i have not found any document which says **how to identify and set properties for the fields** in the pdf. 
 Anyone with any lead on how to do it will be a great help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PDF there is a property called "Required", if you set this property to be true then DocuSign on transforming pdf via transformPdfFields  will make that field madatory in DocuSign. You will find more details in the below link:

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm#Transfor

Answer (score 0):

adding required='true' in the html and converting it into pdf solved my problem. i have attached a screenshot of a sample html to this answer.

[image]